# Sort wp_query by sum of two meta fields

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, templates

Hi I have two custom fields amount1 and amount2. I want to sort my posts in descending order of the sum of amount1 & amount2. How can I achieve this? I know for a single custom field I can do this:

```
'meta_key' => 'amount1', 'orderby' => 'meta_value_num','order' => 'DESC'
```

Comment: That is not possible with a wp_query. What you can do is the usual php calculation and then sort accordingly. Or you write a custom sql_query that does the job. But then you're not using wp_query anymore.

Comment: The sum of  the custom fields would match with which attribute of your posts?

Comment: I figured this out, created a third field, which is updated with sum of two previous fields, and sorted via wp_query